# How to get an SSRS report to show 0 values

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report which is presenting a count on the amount times some particular options are chosen from a table in access.

For example, of these 100 records not necessarily every option has been picked, let's say the breakdown is as follows

- Option a 32
- Option b 28
- Option c 0
- Option d 0
- Option e 40
- Options f-j 0

When I run my report it will then only give me the rows of Option a,b and e but how do I get to show all 10 options even the ones with 0 values?

**Update:** This is the code that the query pulls the data from

```
SELECT Agent, Team, First_Choice_Options, Start_Time FROM Record 
 WHERE (Start_Time >= CONVERT(DATE, @Startdate)) 
   AND (Start_Time < CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Enddate))) 
   AND (Team = 'Triage') AND (Agent IN (@Agent))
```

Comment: You need to show how your dataset is populated.

Comment: This the code that the query pulls the data from 

SELECT        Agent, Team, First_Choice_Options, Start_Time
FROM            Record
WHERE        (Start_Time >= CONVERT(DATE, @Startdate)) AND (Start_Time < CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Enddate))) AND (Team = 'Triage') AND (Agent IN (@Agent))

Comment: It's better to update your original question rather than add comments - gives you a greater chance of somebody answering.

Does option d (for example) exist in the database? If so, please show the values for that row matching the columns you are querying in your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a SQL thing, nothing specific to Reporting Services. SSRS will only display what is returned from the data source. So, you need to change up your query to return the options that are not getting any activity. An example is below. The SELECT statement toward the bottom is where the trick is; the LEFT JOIN does this for you. Everything else is just to get the code to work so I could test this.

```
CREATE TABLE Record (Agent varchar(30), 
    Team varchar(30), 
    First_Choice_Options varchar(30), 
    Start_Time datetime);

INSERT INTO Record VALUES ('Some Agent','Triage','Option A','2016-06-05'),
    ('Some Agent','Triage','Option A','2016-06-10'),
    ('Some Agent','Triage','Option B','2016-06-15'),
    ('Some Agent','Triage','Option B','2016-06-20'),
    ('Some Agent','Triage','Option A','2016-06-25')

CREATE TABLE Options (First_Choice_Options varchar(30))

INSERT INTO Options VALUES ('Option A'),('Option B'),('Option C'),('Option D')

DECLARE @Startdate datetime = '2016-06-01',
    @Enddate datetime = '2016-06-30',
    @Agent varchar(30) = 'Some Agent'

SELECT O.First_Choice_Options AS Options, SUM(IIF(R.First_Choice_Options IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS Options_Count 
FROM Options O LEFT JOIN Record R
ON O.First_Choice_Options = R.First_Choice_Options
AND (Start_Time >= CONVERT(DATE, @Startdate)) 
    AND (Start_Time < CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Enddate))) 
    AND (Team = 'Triage') AND (Agent IN (@Agent))
GROUP BY O.First_Choice_Options

DROP TABLE Record
DROP TABLE Options
```

If you run this against a testing database, you will see what the result look like. Option A and B will have counts, option C and D will report 0 (zero) for the count. This code assumes you have some sort of Options like table in your data source.

```
Options                        Options_Count
------------------------------ -------------
Option A                       3
Option B                       2
Option C                       0
Option D                       0
```

Good luck!

Comment: @DanTracey, glad it worked for you. Please, consider marking the answer as accepted.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer